# the filename property of NSOpenPanel is deprecated, what else to use?

Tags: objective-c

This works just fine, but I get a deprecation warning on filename.  I haven't found an alternative though, is there one?

```
filePath = [[zOpenPanel filename] retain]
```

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000308-BAJCGCJC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

filename
Returns the absolute pathname of the file currently shown in the panel. (Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6. Use URL instead.)

URL
Returns the absolute pathname of the file currently shown in the panel as a URL.

- (NSURL *)URL

So, I think `filePath = [[zOpenPanel URL] retain]`

Comment: but zOpenPanel URL returns a local file path like: "file: //some/path" instead of "/some/path"

Comment: Yes, and you can send `-absolutePath` to the URL to get the path.